# UISearchBar as UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, uisearchbar

I added a `UISearchBar` as `UIBarButtonItem` (right one). I need to display the "Cancel" button but I'm not able to display it. The app I'm developing is for the iPad and is written in Objective-C. 
Just to share with you, the desired behaviour is to increase the width of the search bar when it receive the focus (+50px to the left), so I have to find a solution that is suitable with this requirements also.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Is there any good reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

`UISearchBar` is supposed to be set as a navigation item `titleView` attribute, so this might be the first issue you are experiencing. Then you can tell the search bar to display its cancel button via the `showsCancelButton` property. This should fix your issue with the cancel button not being displayed. Then you can use the `UISearchBarDelegate` methods in order animate the search bar when it comes in/out of focus.

The code below shows all of these in action.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UISearchBarDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UISearchBar *searchBar;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.searchBar = [UISearchBar new];
    self.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;

    self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchBar;
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    // Animate to new position
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    // Animate back to original position
}

@end
```

PS: It is impossible to add a `UISearchBar` instance as a `UIBarButtonItem`. It actually causes an incompatible pointers types warning and a crash at runtime. This is probably the reason for people downvoting your question.